# MongoDB fetch all the id from the other document and make it's value in array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 2 documents where 1st document contains data and its reference key is in another document.

So I want to map both the table where collection A's id is not in collection B.

I have tried $unwind, $in, $nin but it is not working.

I have tried with aggregation as well.

ie. Consider SQL join where 1 table primary key becomes reference of 2nd table

Comment: Can you provide sample documents and the aggregations you have tried so far?